# How to read and write a map of string and a structure to a file

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-serialization, boost-regex

The task I tried to accomplish was a set of strings which have to be stored into a `std::set` and then save it to a file with a number assigned to each `set`.
and I managed to accomplish it by below code using some `boost` functions

```
void WriteToFile()
{
   std::set<std::string> ptotoList = {"John", "Kelly", "Amanda", "Kim"};
   std::set<std::string> etotoList = {"Jo", "Ke", "Am", "Ki"};
   const std::string solMsg = SerializeCutoverListMsg (ptotoList,etotoList);
   std::string msgToBeSaved = 1 + ":" + solMsg;
   std::ofstream outStream (FileName.string().c_str());
   outStream << boost::algorithm::join(msgsToBeSaved, "\n") << endl;

}

string SerializeCutoverListMsg(const std::set& pList, const const std::set&  eList)
{
   return boost::algorithm::join(eList, ",") + ";" + boost::algorithm::join(pList, ",");
}
```

Using this function the Output I generate resembles like below and I save it in a file, I have a number assigned to each `set`

```
  1:John,Kelly,Amanda,Kim;Jo,Ke,Am,Ki
```

And to Read the same data i used the below code

```
 void ReadFromFile()
 {
 std::ifstream wssmAssetListFile(someFilename.c_str());
 string msgLine;
 while ( getline (wssmAssetListFile, msgLine) )
   {
        boost::algorithm::split_regex( result, msgLine, boost::regex( ":" ) ) ;   
         const string& groupId = result[0];
        ---------
   }
 }
```

Now the data that belonged to a `set` changed to a `map` , and the data that has to be read and written looks like below

```
struct test
{
  string a;
  string b;
}
void WriteToFile()
{
  std::map<int, test> eList,pList ;
  eList["John"] = {"dummy", "dummy1"};
  pList["Jo"] = {"dummy", "dummy1"};
   and so on...
}
```

}

I would need help how to write the data like below and read it like I did above just for set

> 1:John{"dummy", "dummy1"},Kelly{"dummy", "dummy1"},Amanda{"dummy", "dummy1"},Kim{"dummy", "dummy1"};Jo{"dummy", "dummy1"},Ke{"dummy", "dummy1"},Am{"dummy", "dummy1"},Ki{"dummy", "dummy1"}

Initially we had `set` of strings but now each string contains a structure and thus I had to use a `map` as each value in the `set` had its corresponding values

Appreciate your help on this

Comment: I would split by the record delimiter `;` first. Create a list of "records" and then iterate over the records, split on `:`, and then construct the map from the "record" value.

Comment: @Ingenioushax you don't have to split anything by; that's isn't whts required it's a set changed to hash now and dealing with it is a bit deep

Comment: Ah. Misunderstood the question.